# how do I install npm packages in linux machine

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, npm-install

I've installed `nodejs v7.5.0` and `npm v4.1.2` in my 32 bit linux mint machine. while I'm typin' `npm install` into terminal, it gives me these informations instead of being installed npm packages are:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.7 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN shwokat@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN shwokat@1.0.0 No repository field
```

Now where's my wrong? how to solve it and install npm packages correctly, please let me know?

Comment: It should still install OK ... Warning only due to 32 bit ... node is sitting atop a JavaScript engine called V8 written in c++ ... npm install often under the covers is compiling code ... Not to worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sudo npm install npm -g`

Go through [the official guide](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/).

Comment: how to solve it and install npm packages correctly..was the question...here is the answer..i myself have installed with this command

Comment: Ahh, looks like I read your command wrong, honest mistake. Sorry for the inconvenience.